# fastest way to filter an 2D array with the content of other array in vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, 2d

Well i have over 200.000 lines in a workbook, so i need the fastest way to handle this data.

My simpler approach of filter data to temp sheet, make some calculation and delete sheet is taking huge amount of time, so i think that if i worked with arrays i could boost things up.

I created an array with dynamic range to hold all data and i have the unique records too in a different array (the days), but i needed to loop the main array and filter the day, so i can for example make a simple sum on results for that day.
The day is in column 3 and value_to_sum in column 6.
I have a code that works on 1d array but how can i get it to work in a multiple field array?

```
f_array = Filter(main_array, "smith")
```

I simple want to get sum of values for each day

Comment: you are looking at loading an additional array with qualifying values whilst doing a loop of main array. Depending on where placing output just have the additional array same size as initial array. During the loop qualifying is determined by arr(i,3) i.e. 3rd column ie array starts at 1.

Comment: `Filter` works only in 1D arrays. I know how to extract a row/column slice (1D array), but I cannot imagine how this will help you... How many columns does your array have?

Comment: No slicing needed. They can use Application.Match on other array. If match found in other array against column 3 of main array then add current row 1 to final array. Otherwise, you have error trapped by Application.Match in a variant variable. match array would be 1D.  Should be plenty of examples on SO. If I have understood correctly, this is a common technique. You would loop just the rows of main array and look at 3rd column. IDK whether Match is much less performant than a loop of the match array.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of your data and try explaining what you need to extract?

Comment: Additionally, you could avoid variant variable for Match return by wrapping `If Not IsError(Application.Match(...`

Comment: this is my data http://prntscr.com/1025fwd. Simple want to sum val1 for the day

Comment: So, do you have an array containing the unique date values (Column C:C) and need to summarize 'val1', 'val2' and 'val3' for specific 'device'/unique 'date'. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: In your picture there is only one 'device'. Would you like to summarize only on the unique date, or for each 'device', too, if many?

Comment: there are 3 devices. thks.

Comment: This will complicate a little the issue, but the code will takes three times more time... I prepared a piece of code which returns only by date. I will post the code and please, test it and send some feedback. Now, it is late in my country and I will see your comment tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. According to the unique date array it will take more on less time. Just curious how much it takes processing your existing data range. Now, it returns in the same sheet, starting from "M2" cell. It can be easily adapted to return anywhere:

```
Sub SummarizePerDate()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long
 Dim arr, arrD, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet with the data to be processed
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arr = sh.Range("A2:G" & lastR).value 'put the data to be processed in an array
 arrD = sh.Range("K2:K9").value       'use here your array of unique date values
                                      'I used this range when tried testing
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrD), 1 To 4)

 For i = 1 To UBound(arrD)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arrD(i, 1) = arr(j, 3) Then
            arrFin(i, 1) = arrD(i, 1)
            arrFin(i, 2) = arrFin(i, 2) + arr(j, 5)
            arrFin(i, 3) = arrFin(i, 3) + arr(j, 6)
            arrFin(i, 4) = arrFin(i, 4) + arr(j, 7)
        End If
    Next j
 Next
 sh.Range("M2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect !!. 203000 lines checked against 91 days in less then a second..

Answer (score 0):

A faster method than working with arrays, with the added benefit of being much simpler, cleaner, and easier to maintain, would be to execute an SQL statement against the worksheet.

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to the latest version **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** (usually 6.0).

Then you could write code like the following:

```vb
Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT device, Data, Sum(val3) AS SumOfVal3 " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "GROUP BY device, Data"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString
```

The resulting [**Recordset** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-ado) will have three columns: `device`, `Data`, and the sum per grouping of `device` and `Data`.

Once you have the recordset, you can do one of a number of things:

- Use the [**EOF**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/bof-eof-properties-ado) property, the [**MoveNext** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado), and the [**Fields** collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/fields-collection-ado) to iterate over the recordset and read the values:

  ```vb
  Do While Not rs.EOF
      Debug.Print rs("device")
      Debug.Print rs("Data")
      Debug.Print rs("SumOfVal3")
      rs.MoveNext
  Loop
  ```
- Convert it to a 2-D array, using the [**GetRows** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/getrows-method-ado):

  ```vb
  Dim arr As Variant
  arr = rs.GetRows

  ' Indexes are zero-based, so the following line:
  Debug.Print arr(1, 0)
  ' will print the value at the second column -- Data -- in the first row
  ```
- Convert it into a single long string, using the [**GetString** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/getstring-method-ado); you can specify the column and row delimiters of your choice.
- Paste it into a new Excel worksheet, using the Excel [**Range.CopyFromRecordset** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset)

Note that by default the recordset will be opened in forward-only mode, so you won't be able to move back and forth within the recordset; and in readonly mode, so you cannot make any changes to the data in the recordset.