# VBA for automatically converting the received list to the wanted format

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write the VBA code to help me convert the order list which I receive from clients to the format which can be processed by the ERP system in my company but there are some parts which I don’t know how to deal with due to my limited knowledge on VBA. My idea is to first create a new worksheet and fill in the headers stored in the string for the wanted columns and then record macro to use vlookup function to pull the data from the original order list. However, I only need the data belonging to Factory A(There is one column which denotes which order belongs to which factory) . As you can see from the picture below, the data belonging to factory starts from 26th row and ends at 63th rows(not the last row of this table), which means that I only need the data in this range. Is there any way to create a function for locating this range of data(the starting row and end row).
[An example of the order list described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ais8.png)

Comment: I would use index() with match() as it is more flexible than vlookup. Also I would use a template to get the info and save as without vba but that is just me...

Comment: Yes you are right. That's also what I am doing now. I created a template to lookup all the wanted data and then fill them in but I recently was thinking about writing VBA code to automate the whole process.

Comment: We cannot "see"  the range 26 to 63. If this interval must always be used, it will not be a problem, but if the criteria to identify it should be the string  "Factory A" in the C:C column, it will be OK. Then, do you need all the range between the two mentioned rows?

Comment: You received two answers. Didn't you find some time to test them? If tested, it is good to mark as **accepted answer** the one you like better. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works as it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It returns the extracted slice in a newly created sheet. It can return wherever you need:

```
Sub extractSlice()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSl, firstAddress As String, cols As String
 Dim Cel As Range, searchStr As String, firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, newSh As Worksheet
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet to be processed
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 searchStr = "Factory A"
 arr = sh.Range("A2:F" & lastR).value  'put the range to be processed in an array
 cols = "A:F" 'the columns to be processed for the slicing
 
'find the first cell with the search string:
 Set Cel = sh.Range("C2:C" & lastR).Find(what:=searchStr, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows)
 If Not Cel Is Nothing Then            'if the cell has been find:
    firstAddress = Cel.Address         'put its address in a string
    firstRow = Cel.row - 1             'obtain first row of the slice (-1 because the array starts from the second row)
    Do 'loop through the range having the search string:
        Set Cel = sh.Range("C2:C" & lastR).FindNext(Cel)
        If Not Cel Is Nothing Then
            If Cel.row - 1 > lastRow Then lastRow = Cel.row - 1
        End If
    Loop While Cel.Address <> firstAddress 'exit the loop when the first address is returned again
    
    'Create the necessary array slice:
    arrSl = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(" & firstRow & ":" & lastRow & ")"), Evaluate("COLUMN(" & cols & ")"))

    'insert a new sheet immediately after the one to be processed
    'You can use here an existing sheet from a different workbook, too:
    Set newSh = Worksheets.Add(After:=sh)

    'drop the array contents at once (very fast):
    newSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrSl), UBound(arrSl, 2)).value = arrSl
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When presented with this kind of problem -- parsing and filtering a set of data on an Excel worksheet -- I find it much simpler to treat the Excel worksheet as a database table, using ActiveX Data Objects.

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to the latest version of **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** (usually 6.0).

Then you could write code similar to the following:

```vb
Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"
Const sheetname As String = "Sheet1"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT * " & _
    "FROM [" & sheetname & "$] " & _
    "WHERE [Factory Code] = 'Factory A'"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString
```

You'll have to supply the following:

- the path to the Excel file
- the name of the worksheet

Once you have a Recordset object, you can do any one of a number of things with the recordset, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66309056/111794).